# Variation of MAX 3-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, 3-sat

Suppose we are given a 3CNF, and we want to know whether k clauses from this 3CNF can be satisfied (k being any natural number)?

I'm trying to think of an efficient algorithm to solve this problem. This is sort of a variation of the MAX 3-SAT, but with a fixed k. If we have m clauses, checking naively would get $\binom{m}{k}$ comparisons, but this seems factorial (if we approximate with Sterling's formula, exponential) complexity.

What could be an efficient way to check this? I must be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Is $k$ a fixed constant? If so, $\binom{m}{k}=O(m^k)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't know whether "3CNF" means *exactly* 3 literals per clause, or

*at most* 3 literals per clause. ​ I will address the more general case.)

Empty clauses can't be satisfied, so removing them affects

neither the maximum nor which assignments achieve that.

If ​ 2$\cdot$k ≤ #_of_non-empty_clauses ​ then YES, since the expected number of those clauses satisfied by a random assignment is at least half of #_of_non-empty_clauses,

so at least one assignment satisfies at least half of the non-empty clauses.

(One can efficiently-and-deterministically *find* such an

assignment via the [method of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_conditional_probabilities).)

Thus, your problem can be [kernelized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernelization) in linear time into less than 2$\cdot$k clauses.

Answer (score 2):

This is the decision version of MAX-3SAT, which is known to be NP-complete. In particular, if you choose $k = m$ then you get the classical NP-complete problem 3SAT.